# How long before boarding gates close are last calls first announced?

Tags: air-travel, legal, regulations, timetables

I wonder how long before boarding gates close last calls are first announced. E.g., is it 15 minutes, 30 minutes prior to the closure of the boarding gates, depending on the boarding staff's mood, the airport, or the airline's policy.

Comment: The answers to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168328/must-airlines-switch-to-last-call-before-closing-the-gate strongly suggest that no standards exist.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure any answer to this question would be actionable.  The only practical advice seems to be "do not rely on a last call announcement being made, and if one is made, do not make any assumptions about how much time you have to get to the gate".

Comment: @NateEldredge if the answer is 10 minutes then this is clearly actionable. how much time you have to get to the gate can sometimes be known

Comment: This is so indeterminate across the world that no answer would be useful anyway.

Comment: @Nij knowing that This is so indeterminate across the world  is useful. You're welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Theres nothing in any ICAO or IATA documentation that I can find - which is why airlines can issue a “first and only call” for flights as well.

Comment: @Moo thanks for checking! You're welcome to convert your comment into an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The airline will close the gate at the gate closing time stated on your boarding pass. That's the only thing that matters.

"Last call" announcement are entirely optional and there are no specific rules or consistent practices that are employed. Mostly it's done if a passenger is late that has checked luggage. The airline will typically try to call them since otherwise they have to unload the bags which is a pain in the neck.